# Getting data from POST [id] form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

On a table that displays data from a database, I have a form that has a text area on which a user can type a receipt number and submit to save in a database for a specif row. The PHP code below is what updates the database after the form is submitted.
I want to pick the rest of the details for the specific row so I used the `$_POST['id']` on which the receipt has been submitted. The `id` is the primary key. I'm however having a challenge since I can't fetch data from the database using `$id = $_POST['id'];`I created before outside the function The `update` statement works perfectly but the `SELECT STATEMENT`doesn't . How do I go about it? Any one?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$rec = $_POST['receipt'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
//reate connection

$sql = "UPDATE customer SET `receipt` = '".$_POST['receipt']."', `date_entered` = NOW(), `receipt_lock` = 1 WHERE `id` = '".$_POST['tid']."' AND receipt_lock = 0";
   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     // echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      exit(); 
   $conn->close();
}


function wall(){

global $recp;
global $id;

// Create con

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id ='$id'";

 $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultarr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1); // fetch data


                $name = $resultarr['name'];
                echo "$name"; //Does not display

                $amount = $resultarr['amount'];
                $transaction_id = $resultarr['trans_id'];
                $date = $resultarr['time_paid'];
    }
else {

echo "this is not right!;
}
wall();
```

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: You also have `global $recp` when you are setting `$rec = $_POST['receipt'];`. Anyway, `$_POST` is a super global, you can access it everywhere, including in your function. No need for nasty `global`'s. The bigger issue you have is, as @MattS pointed out, that you're wide open to SQL Injections.

Comment: Try with echo $name rather than echo "$name"

Comment: First, SLQ injection. Second, in your first query (You didnt open a connection?) you use $_POST['tid']? Typo or just right?
The last else statement where you echo `this is not right` has no if statement? Also you are passing the id's as strings, maybe try them without the double quotes? Your code is very unstructured. Are you coding in notepad?

Comment: The update statement works fine. The select statement is failling to fetch data from the database for the row updated.

Comment: If the update statement (using `tid`) works fine, then shouldn't `$id = $_POST['id']` really be `$id = $_POST['tid']`? You're using two different ID's for the update and select, as it is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring all the (valid) questions about SQL security and just addressing your problem - how about passing the $id variable as a parameter to your wall function.?

```
wall($id);

function wall($id){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id ='$id'";
    // ... use prepared statements for security...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `$_POST['tid']` instead of `$_POST['id']` or `$id` in your SQL-query.

Comment: The update statement works fine. The select statement is faillin to fetch data from the database for the row updated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there is a big nono, in terms of security. Make sure you escape your POST parameters before adding them inside your query.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $id);
```

http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Think about sending data as parameters of a function function wall($id) instead of a global parameter.

Comment: `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string;`? Forgot some parentheses and arguments, i believe? ;-) A better way would be to use Prepared Statements, though, since that will remove any risk of SQL Injections.

Comment: thanks for clearing it out, I missed it during the update.